# Entity Framework 6 - Error: 1109 Property is not mapped

Tags: entity-framework

We have been using EF6 on a project and have been encountering numerous issues with it.

The latest issue is that we have started getting a compilation error:  Error 1109: Property 'Procedure8' is not mapped.

There is no such entity/property as procedure8. Examining the edmx file on the line indicated shows a completely different entity.  There will be around 10 or 20 of these errors created from procedure1 through to procedure20, then it will repeat the 11007 error for every class in that was generated.

If we create the .ednx file from scratch and generate the model from the database, it imports all of the tables and stored procedures (about 250 odd of the latter).  We then need to generate entities() class from the context.tt file to get all of the classes.  Doing this successfully creates the entities and we get the .cs files in the project folder but results in the above error.

We have tried doing a 'generate database from model' to get the SQL file, as some people have suggested that this is required to generate additional files.  However, this removes all of the stored procedures from the model store and we have to delete the .edmx file and start again.

Does anyone have any ideas on what actually causes this error and how to get the EF work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue we think is that the edmx file had become corrupted.  This was deleted from the project along with all of the generated files.

A new edmx file was added to the project with the same name and re-generated, this created what looked like all of the correct files, but still failed to compile.

The solution was to remove the connection string from the app.config file, then generate a new edmx (visual studio add new item).  It will prompt to create a new connection string, then ask to import all of the tables, views and stored procedures.

Once it is done importing everything it is necessary to then wait a very long time while some post processing is done - the visual progress indicator does not always appear.

No other actions are required from there other than building the project.

Not sure why the product is so sensitive around connection strings.